# SQL multiple AND and OR

Tags: sql

Can anyone help me un derstand the syntax of using AND like 4 times.

I have this piece of code

```
WHERE (ListPrice >= 400) and (ListPrice <= 800) AND (Color = 'Red') OR (Color = 'Black')
```

Once evaluated it gives many other columns which do not have the color red or black. help please

Comment: WHERE (ListPrice >= 400) and (ListPrice <= 800) AND ((Color = 'Red') OR (Color = 'Black'))

Comment: Select * FROM mytable WHERE (ListPrice >= 400) and (ListPrice <= 800) AND ((Color = 'Red') OR (Color = 'Black'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should change it to

```
WHERE ((ListPrice >= 400) AND (ListPrice <= 800)) AND (Color = 'Red' OR Color = 'Black')
```

Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: I am supposed to use the operators instead of BETWEEN and IN. That is why I opted to use >=, <=, AND and OR

Comment: The thing is `AND` have precedence over `OR` that is why you need to add parenthesis.

Comment: Oh, you can replace it with ((ListPrice >= 400) and (ListPrice <= 800))

Comment: @winter just update your answer to meet OP requirement and I upvote your answer.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You answer first and deserve that first upvote :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE (ListPrice BETWEEN 400 and 800) AND (Color in ('Red','Black'))
```

Comment: This, you're writing in SQL not C. Use its really powerful tools.

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate `OR` separately then `AND` it with other condition. See this

```
WHERE (ListPrice >= 400) and (ListPrice <= 800) AND (Color = 'Red' OR Color = 'Black')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below

```
select * from t1 where pr >=400 and pr<=800 and (co='Red' or co='Black' );
```

Below is the test--

```
create table t1 (pr number(10),co varchar2(10));

insert  into t1 values (700,'Red');
insert  into t1 values (500,'Black');
insert  into t1 values (200,'Black');
insert  into t1 values (900,'Red');
commit;

select * from t1 where pr >=400 and pr<=800 and (co='Red' or co='Black' );
```

Output--

```
PR  CO

700 Red

500 Black
```

Answer (score 1):

Parenthesis are important!

Example:

```
WHERE ((ListPrice >= 400) and (ListPrice <= 800) AND (Color = 'Red')) OR (Color = 'Black')
```

Would forsure return anything in black or red.
When it returns something red it also returns the other ones you have there.